# display array of dictionaries in UITableView

Tags: objective-c, ios

i am newbie so please dont thrash me thanks...
i have the following the array of dictionaries

```
           NSMutableArray *array;
           NSDictionary *dict,*dict1;
```

viewdidload method

```
           array=[NSMutableArray array];
           dict=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"12.00",@"Tomato"];
           [array addObject:dict];

           dict1=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"75.00",@"Cauliflower"];
           [array addObject:dict1];
```

i want to display the following items in uitableview format

tomato          12.00

Cauliflower     75.00

Answer (score 3, accepted):

create the data like this.

```
   array=[NSMutableArray array];
   dict=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"12.00",@"price",@"Tomato",@"name", nil];
   [array addObject:dict];

  dict1=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"75.00",@"price",@"Cauliflower",@"name", nil];
   [array addObject:dict1];
```

then display on your tableView

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] ;
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@  %@",[[array objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"name"],[[array objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"price"] ];
  return cell;
}
```

Comment: i get an error in the last line,and isnt it objectForKey:@"name",isnt there a colon?

Comment: Thanks..but why is the price being shown on the left side,am i supposed to modify the dictionary so that it shows on the right side?